# Automator takes screenshot of background instead of window

Tags: macos, screenshot, apple-m1, automator

System specs: mac OS Monterrey V12.5, Apple M1 chip 2020

I am making an application which will take a screenshot of a video, and take the timestamp of the current point in this video, after which both the timestamp and screenshot will be send to a numbers file (mac OS excel like program).

I could not find an application to do this and I tried to get it working using python as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73179094/tkinter-intermittent-segmentation-fault-when-setting-master-screen-transparent/73198072#73198072) but was unable to. Now because I am on Mac I have decided to use Automator instead. I am currently on the screenshot part and Automator has a build in screenshot functionality.

Unfortunately, this screenshot does not detect browser or application windows, it will only take a screenshot of my background.

I have no idea why this is but I suspect it might have to do with permissions related to the M1 chip.

I tried different monitors and simplyfying the automation to just taking a screenshot, but so far nothing has helped, I could not find others online who had a similar problem.

If there is any information missing from this post I will be happy to provide it.

Edit: It seems to be some kind of permission issue, automator CAN take screenshots within Safari, now I just need to find a way to do so in firefox.

Comment: If its just taking the background image, then the automation software is not being told to activate the web window first.    I'm not sure how you would tell that software to select the web window you want to take a screenshot from, you might even be able to hack something in with using TAB TAB TAB until it hits the right window then takes the screen shot if you can make keyboard macros.  Granted it has to be exact every time, an additional window would throw it off, but you could sort of get a system where it tabs X amount of times to get the active window before screenshot.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, but something else was the problem. I solved the issue, it turns out the M1 chip has a special permission for screen recording, adding my application to this permission allows me to take screenshots of windows other than Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, it turns out that the M1 chip has a special permission for screen recording, adding my Automator application to this permission list will allow it to take screenshots of all windows.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the update, how did you end up figuring that out, just some research?

Comment: I made an automator app that made a screenshot using the build in primitives, and then apple automatically asks for permission and when you click to expand to give it it opens the permission window in the screenshot list.